# How to group and display table data in a horizontal way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

Transactions Table :

| Client_ID | AccountType | TransactionDate | TransactionType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C100111001 | C | 1997-12-13 | R | 60 |
| C100111001 | C | 1997-12-20 | D | 800 |
| C100111001 | E | 1997-12-15 | D | 300 |
| C100111001 | E | 1997-12-23 | R | 100 |
| C100111002 | C | 1997-03-20 | D | 1000 |
| C100111002 | C | 1997-03-25 | R | 40 |
| C100111002 | C | 1997-05-20 | D | 500 |
| C100111002 | C | 1997-08-20 | R | 80 |
| C100111003 | C | 1998-12-25 | D | 1000 |
| C100111003 | C | 1999-10-01 | R | 100 |
| C100111003 | C | 1999-12-01 | D | 100 |
| C100111003 | V | 1998-09-11 | R | 100 |
| C100111003 | V | 1998-10-12 | D | 70 |
| C100111003 | V | 1998-11-13 | D | 30 |
| C100113002 | C | 1999-02-04 | D | 1000 |

My Query:

```
select  AccType, SUM(Amount) as 'Amount' , year(TransDate) as 'Year'
from    Transactions
where   (year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='R')
     or (year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='R')
     or (year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='R')
group by AccType, TransType, year(Transdate)
order by year(TransDate)
```

My Result Table:

| AccType | Amount | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2300.00 | 1997 |
| C | 180.00 | 1997 |
| S | 300.00 | 1997 |
| S | 100.00 | 1997 |
| C | 1000.00 | 1998 |
| V | 100.00 | 1998 |
| V | 100.00 | 1998 |
| C | 1100.00 | 1999 |
| C | 100.00 | 1999 |

Desired Output Table:

| AccType | 1997 Credit | 1997 Debit | 1998 Credit | 1998 Debit | 1999 Credit | 1999 Debit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2300.0000 | 180.0000 | 1000.0000 | 0.0000 | 1100.0000 | 100.0000 |
| E | 300.0000 | 100.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 |
| V | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 100.0000 | 100.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 |

At the top I have the query that is not giving me desired result. Please refer to the Desired Output Table and help me.  In my result table the data is being shown kind of veritically where as I want the data in horizontal format as per the Desired Output Table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I am sorry I am new on the platform, should I remove the SQL Server tag? I know that is not entirely correct but I thought that is how it should be done.

Comment: Sure. Thank you

Comment: I am unable to understand how to print multiple columns in select query. Because my output is coming vertically. And in the question the desired output is horizontal

Comment: A quick google on how to format text in stackoverflow will answer your questions.

Comment: Thank you will try and get familiar with the platform.  Also, pease let me know how do I get the desired output for Transactions table , I need to print the credit (R) or debit (D) for each year between 1997 to 1999 for each type of Account (C, S or V) .

Comment: Dale K could you please at least give some hint on the sql query? I am completely clueless.  Thank you in advance 
`
select AccType, SUM(Amount) as 'Amount', year(TransDate) as 'Year' from Transactions
where year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='D' or year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='R'
or year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='D' or year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='R'
or year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='D' or year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='R'
group by AccType, TransType, year(Transdate)
order by year(TransDate)
`

Comment: If you provide a [MRE] as working dbfiddle I'll have a look.

Comment: Well for one thing, you cannot just mix together `and`s and `or`s like that without parenthesis to group them correctly.

Comment: I have edited the question and tried to put everything together. Thank you and can you please check the question now if it is comprehensible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AccType, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1997 AND TransType = 'D' THEN Amount END), 0) `1997 Credit`,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1997 AND TransType = 'R' THEN Amount END), 0) `1997 Debit`,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1998 AND TransType = 'D' THEN Amount END), 0) `1998 Credit`,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1998 AND TransType = 'R' THEN Amount END), 0) `1998 Debit`,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1999 AND TransType = 'D' THEN Amount END), 0) `1999 Credit`,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TransDate) = 1999 AND TransType = 'R' THEN Amount END), 0) `1999 Debit`
FROM Transactions
WHERE YEAR(TransDate) IN (1997, 1998, 1999) 
  AND TransType IN ('D', 'R') -- you may remove this condition if 'D' and 'R' are the only possible values
GROUP BY AccType
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0facc2505ccd2c385a8bee6813ea30b).

Comment: Thank you, this works for me wonderfully.
 What is the significance of 0 in COALESCE(.... , 0) ? Is it because of the fact that we have to give at least two values in the list for COALESCE() ?

Comment: @Zoori SUM() may return NULL if say there is no transaction for 1997 with TransType = 'D'. In this case with COALESCE() you get 0 instead of NULL.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for us to tell from what you've given us what it is that you are really looking for, but I'm guessing that it should be something like this:

```
select  AccType, SUM(Amount), year(TransDate) 
from    Transactions
where   (year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1997' and TransType='R')
     or (year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1998' and TransType='R')
     or (year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='D')
     or (year(TransDate)='1999' and TransType='R')
group by AccType, TransType, year(Transdate)
order by year(TransDate)
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you cannot just mix together `AND` operators and `OR` operators without using parenthesis to group them correctly.  Otherwise, they are executed in the order that they appear in the query, which is pretty much never correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comment/suggestion. Can you please check the question now if you are able to understand my question now. I have tried and edited the question. Thanks again!